# Ошибка записи файла .json

Tags: python, json

Пишу небольшую базу данных на Python. И у меня json файл выдаёт ошибку.

Я использую вот такой метод записи

```
with open('user_data.json', "a", encoding = 'utf8') as file:
        json.dump(user_data, file, indent = 1, ensure_ascii = False)
```

Вот тут вылезает ошибка "Ожидался конец файла .json".

```
{
 "0": [
  {
   "Username": "Username",
   "Full Name": "Full Name",
   "ID": ""
  }
 ]
}{ <- Тут ошибка
 "1": [
  {
   "Username": "Username",
   "Full Name": "Full Name",
   "ID": ""
  }
 ]
}
```

Совершенно не понимаю в чём дело. Вроде json я составил правильно, хотя мог ошибиться со структурой.

Comment: Это невалидный json. Видимо вы несколько json-ов в один файл записали. Вместо этого нужно формировать список из ваших записей, и целиком список записывать в json. Не через добавление ("a"), а через полную перезапись ("w"). Если в файле изначально что-то есть, нужно сначала это прочитать, потом туда добавить данные и записать обратно.

Comment: @insolor Так я делал раньше, но у меня случалась проблема, что в какой-то момент код не успевал читать и записывать обратно. Слишком много данных. Поэтому я начал искать другие варианты. Этот показался очень удобным, но с ошибкой)

Comment: Используйте базу данных тогда)

Comment: Если нужно дописывать данные в конец файла, - пусть каждая отдельная строка будет json-ом. (Скармливать парсеру json-а нужно будет построчно.)

Comment: Или используйте yaml.  Для него склеивание валидных файлов дает валидный файл, в отличии от json/xml...

Comment: Хотелось бы через json всё-таки работать, я его хотя бы примерно понимаю. Возможно у меня ошибка конкретно с созданием списка и т.п. Ну буду пробовать, спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Невозможно получить валидный `json` дописыванием в файл. Просто невозможно. Если у вас много обновлений данных - используйте БД. Может даже какую-то `in memory db` типа `redis`. Она периодически и на диск данные сбрасывает. В общем, зависит от сценария, что вам важно - быстро данные обрабатывать или точно всё наработанное сохранить. Можно найти баланс.